# Find negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression in python and gradient loss with respect to w,bF

Tags: python, logistic-regression, backpropagation

**Formula to Find the Cost Function:**

[image: Cost Function]

**Formula to Calculate Gradient Loss for w,b:**

[image: Gradient Loss]

Arguments:

1. w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
2. b -- bias, a scalar
3. X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
4. Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

Return:

1. cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
2. dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
3. db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b

**My Code:**

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(z):
    """
    Compute the sigmoid of z

    Arguments:
    z -- A scalar or numpy array of any size.

    Return:
    s -- sigmoid(z)
    """

    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
    s = None
    s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    return s




# GRADED FUNCTION: propagate

def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
    """
    Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above



    Tips:
    - Write your code step by step for the propagation. np.log(), np.dot()
    """

    m = X.shape[1]

    # FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    A = None                                    # compute activation
    cost = None                                 # compute cost
    k = w * X + b  
    A = sigmoid(k)

    cost = (-Y * np.log(A) - (1 - Y) * np.log(1 - A)).mean() / m
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
    dw = None
    db = None
    db = np.subtract(A , Y)
    dw = np.dot(X,db.T)/m
    db = np.sum(db)/m
    ### END CODE HERE ###

    # assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
    # assert(db.dtype == float)
    # cost = np.squeeze(cost)
    # assert(cost.shape == ())

    grads = {"dw": dw,
             "db": db}

    return grads, cost


w, b, X, Y = np.array([[1.],[2.]]), 2., np.array([[1.,2.,-1.],[3.,4.,-3.2]]), np.array([[1,0,1]])
grads, cost = propagate(w, b, X, Y)
print ("dw = " + str(grads["dw"]))
print ("db = " + str(grads["db"]))
print ("cost = " + str(cost))
```

**My Output:**

```
dw = [[ 0.72851438  0.99581514]                                                                                               
 [ 1.5487967   2.38666712]]                                                                                                   
db = 0.225798060825                                                                                                           
cost = 1.04403235316
```

**Expected Output:**

```
dw = [[ 0.99845601]     [ 2.39507239]]
db = 0.00145557813678
cost = 5.801545319394553
```

Could anybody tell me why my dw dimension is not same with expected output and help to find the cost function?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't belong here but rather to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some small mistakes like you should use `np.sum(Y*np.log(A) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-A)) / m` in place of using `.mean()` and the next mistake that I think is replace `np.subtract(A-Y)` with simple `A-Y` bcz. there is no need for numpy in this. It's working for me.

```
def propagate(w, b, X, Y):
"""
Implement the cost function and its gradient for the propagation explained above

Arguments:
w -- weights, a numpy array of size (num_px * num_px * 3, 1)
b -- bias, a scalar
X -- data of size (num_px * num_px * 3, number of examples)
Y -- true "label" vector (containing 0 if non-cat, 1 if cat) of size (1, number of examples)

Return:
cost -- negative log-likelihood cost for logistic regression
dw -- gradient of the loss with respect to w, thus same shape as w
db -- gradient of the loss with respect to b, thus same shape as b

Tips:
- Write your code step by step for the propagation. np.log(), np.dot()
"""

m = X.shape[1]

# FORWARD PROPAGATION (FROM X TO COST)
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
A = sigmoid(np.dot(w.T,X)+b)                                   # compute activation
cost = -np.sum(Y*np.log(A) + (1-Y)*np.log(1-A)) / m                              # compute cost
### END CODE HERE ###  

# BACKWARD PROPAGATION (TO FIND GRAD)
### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
dw = np.dot(X,(A-Y).T)/m
db = np.sum(A-Y,axis=1)/m
### END CODE HERE ###

assert(dw.shape == w.shape)
assert(db.dtype == float)
cost = np.squeeze(cost)
assert(cost.shape == ())

grads = {"dw": dw,
         "db": db}

return grads, cost
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dw = np.dot(X,db.T)/m
```

is wrong.

Instead of db, it should be multiplied with the derivative of the activation function here, i.e sigmoid,

```
A = sigmoid(k)
dA = np.dot((1-A)*A,dloss.T) # This is the derivative of a sigmoid function

dw = np.dot(X,dA.T)
```

The code is not tested, but the solution would be along this line.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477207/derivative-of-cost-function-for-logistic-regression) to calculate dloss.

Comment: I tried the tip you mentioned but still somewhere mistake is there

Comment: @D_Raja i would suggest you to closely look into the theory. To compute dA we need the derivative of loss function wrt x(See update). Furthermore, there's no point in calculating mean cost and dividing it by m again. .sum()/m might be the correct implementation.